# Missing execute() Method in YouTube Data API

Tags: java, youtube-api

I'm trying to access the YouTube data API, but [this sample code](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/java/youtube-cmdline-search-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/youtube_cmdline_search_sample/Search.java) doesn't seem to work.

My gradle build file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev79-1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.api.client:google-api-client-googleapis:1.4.0-alpha'

}
```

And a minimal test case I tried using is:

```
YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new GsonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {}
}).setApplicationName("youtube-api").build();

YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id");
search.setKey(API_KEY);
search.setQ("search string");
search.execute(); // execute() method does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was referencing the wrong version of the google-api-client library. The correct gradle build script is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev79-1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.17.0-rc'
}
```

Comment: Here's another way to keep up to date with the version: check this page https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3